# Issue in TextToColumns with xlFixedWidth loosing blanks

Tags: vba, excel, text-parsing

I am trying to implement a way to parse many fixed width formats (hundreds of them) with a very simple VBA macro.

The software that generates these formats provides me with a very neat description of them that I already parsed as follows:

```
FD1 FD2 FD3 FD4
--  --  --  --
2   3   3   5
AACCC  FUUUUU
AAHHH  FGGGGG
55HHH  FVVVVV
55HHH--LVVVVV
PPNNN  LVVVVV
PPJJJ--LDDDDD
```

> Obviously this is mock data that I created to make some tests to reproduce the issue.

Notice that my data can or cannot be preceded (or succeeded) by any character, including spaces. I wrote the following 
(very naive and non reviewed) code:

```
Sub LoopParser()
    Const SizesRow = 3
    Const DataStart = "A4"

    Dim ToCut
    ToCut = 0

    Range(DataStart).Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ToCut = ActiveSheet.Cells(SizesRow, ActiveCell.Column).Value

        Call ParseOneField(ActiveCell.Address, CInt(ToCut))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop

    Range(DataStart).Select

End Sub

Sub ParseOneField(TargetCell, DesiredSize As Integer)
    Const MaxLayout = 10000#

    Range(TargetCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range(TargetCell), _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, xlTextFormat), _
                         Array(DesiredSize, xlTextFormat), _
                         Array(MaxLayout, xlTextFormat) _
                         ), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

But it has a problem: When I try to parse the third columns of data the blanks are loose (besides I am using xlTextFormat (2)) to treat them, I always end up with something like this:

```
FD1 FD2 FD3 FD4
--  --  --  --
2   3   3   5
AA  CCC FUU UUU
AA  HHH FGG GGG
55  HHH FVV VVV
55  HHH --L VVVVV
PP  NNN LVV VVV
PP  JJJ --L DDDDD
```

When the expected result would be (preserving blanks in the third field)

```
FD1 FD2 FD3 FD4
--  --  --  --
2   3   3   5
AA  CCC   F UUUUU
AA  HHH   F GGGGG
55  HHH   F VVVVV
55  HHH --L VVVVV
PP  NNN   L VVVVV
PP  JJJ --L DDDDD
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Even a workaround would suffice.

> I am thinking of designing tests to grab any unused character in a given data-set and replace the blanks with it prior to any change, then change the character back to blanks afterwards, but this feels like cheating. :-(

**UPDATE:**

I fell uncomfortable to post a xlsm file to somewhere @sgdva, instead let me give some directions on how to reproduce my exact problem.

Start by heading to [this gist on github](https://gist.github.com/rafareino/b5c9e79479de33e58cdb5ae4ba946fd0), where you will find some excerpts of my code and data, correctly formatted.

Then copy/past the input data into a new spreadsheet, My hope is that excel will recognize the tabs in the first tree rows ans be able to separate the names/sizes into columns, while keeping the next 6 lines as simple text.

Then copy/paste the code into a brand new excel module, and run it against the data.

Let me know in the comments if you still have any problem.

Comment: Any corrections regarding my wording or spell, will be greatly appreciated and a Bonus to me,

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: The third field was supposed to be (" F", " F", " F", "--L", " L", "--L"), 4 of the 6 records, were meant to have spaces in the first positions, but they disappeared. I will improve the question a little

Comment: Hmm I'm still not getting the logic, -probably it's because the pasting data is not being accordingly to cells ranges and stuff-, I have all this data just in A4 for example (    AACCC  FUUUUU). Could you please upload a sample workbook with the data pasted in the desired ranges with the proper format? As well as the expected outcome in the correct order.

Comment: I believe this is a "feature" of Excel --- after splitting it does a TRIM of each field. A cludge workaround is: before splitting, replace spaces with some a dummy char (e.g. $) that you're sure is not in the data, split, then replace the dummy with a space.

Comment: Wonder if there are any way to disable this "great" feature, specially because I am parsing to text format xlTextFormat

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to a solution!!

Even more naive and dirtier than the previous code, but wanna post it here for future reference.

```
Sub LoopParser()
    Const SizesRow = 3
    Const DataStart = "A4"
    Const SizesStart = "A3"

    Dim CutPoint
    Dim EachSize(1) As Integer
    Dim CutPointsArray() As Variant
    Dim CurrentArrayPos As Integer

    CutPoint = 0
    CurrentArrayPos = 0

    Range(SizesStart).Select

    EachSize(0) = CInt(CutPoint)
    EachSize(1) = xlTextFormat

    ReDim Preserve CutPointsArray(0 To CurrentArrayPos)
    CutPointsArray(CurrentArrayPos) = EachSize

    Do
        CurrentArrayPos = CurrentArrayPos + 1
        CutPoint = CutPoint + ActiveSheet.Cells(SizesRow, ActiveCell.Column).Value
        EachSize(0) = CInt(CutPoint)
        EachSize(1) = xlTextFormat

        ReDim Preserve CutPointsArray(0 To CurrentArrayPos)
        CutPointsArray(CurrentArrayPos) = EachSize
        'Call ParseOneField(ActiveCell.Address, CInt(CutPoint))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    Range(DataStart).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range(DataStart), _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=CutPointsArray, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Range(DataStart).Select

End Sub
```

The greater changes are:

1. The sizes must be summed up to each `CutPoint`, so instead of an array of sizes, we have a `CutPointsArray`
2. Instead of parsing each column, one at a time, I parsed the sizes and constructed the `CutPointsArray` in one loop and then used it to parse the data in one single step